# Как сделать что бы при изменении пароля или почты в профиле пользователя, отображались изменения и в файрбаз

Tags: email

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.Model.User;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.Storage;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    TextView editname, editpassword,editemail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        editname = findViewById(R.id.editname);
        editpassword = findViewById(R.id.changepassword);
        firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth.getInstance();
        editemail = findViewById(R.id.editemail);
        String uid;
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
        editpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showPasswordChangeDailog();
    }
});
        editname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showNamephoneupdate("name");
    }
});
        editemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setEditemail();

            }
        });
    }

private  void setEditemail(){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_emailedit, null);
    final EditText oldemail = view.findViewById(R.id.oldemaillog);
    final EditText newemail = view.findViewById(R.id.newemaillog);
    final EditText passttt = view.findViewById(R.id.passlog);
    Button editemail = view.findViewById(R.id.updateemail);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(view);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    editemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String oldem = oldemail.getText().toString().trim();
            String newem = newemail.getText().toString().trim();
            String pass1 = passttt.getText().toString().trim();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(oldem)) {
                Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Current Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newem)) {
                Toast.makeText(profile.this, "New Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            updateemail(oldem, newem, pass1);

        }


    });

}
    private void updateemail(String oldem, String newem, String pass1) {
        final  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(oldem, pass1);
        user.reauthenticate(authCredential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d("value", "User re-authenticated.");
                        user.updateEmail(newem)

                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Пароль успешно заменен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });;
    }
    private void showPasswordChangeDailog() {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_editpassword, null);
        final EditText oldpass = view.findViewById(R.id.oldpasslog);
        final EditText newpass = view.findViewById(R.id.newpasslog);
        Button editpass = view.findViewById(R.id.updatepass);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(view);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        editpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String oldp = oldpass.getText().toString().trim();
                String newp = newpass.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(oldp)) {
                    Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Current Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newp)) {
                    Toast.makeText(profile.this, "New Password cant be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                updatePassword(oldp, newp);

            }
        });
    }

    private void updatePassword(String oldp, final String newp) {
        final  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        AuthCredential authCredential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user.getEmail(), oldp);
        user.updatePassword(newp);
        user.reauthenticate(authCredential)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        user.updatePassword(newp)

                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Пароль успешно заменен", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void showNamephoneupdate(final String key) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Update" + key);

        // creating a layout to write the new name
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Enter" + key);
        layout.addView(editText);
        builder.setView(layout);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                final String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {

                    // Here we are updating the new name
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put(key, value);
                    databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).updateChildren(result).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                            // after updated we will show updated
                            Toast.makeText(profile.this, " updated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Unable to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    if (key.equals("name")) {
                        final DatabaseReference databaser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
                        Query query = databaser.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(true);
                        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String child = databaser.getKey();
                                    dataSnapshot1.getRef().child("uname").setValue(value);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(profile.this, "Unable to update", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

код юзера

```
public class User {
    public String name, email, pass;
    public User() {
    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + "." + email + "-" + pass;
    }
    public User(String name,String email,String pass){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
}
```